Multiple matches with capture groups in PowerShell regex
I'm trying to understand why the following regular expression does not do what I expect in Powershell.
\["(Total|Group1|Group2)",(\d+),\d*,,,,,\d+,\d+\]
I would expect this to return nine matches as there are three groupings that match this expression, each with two tokens. Regex101 gives me the results I expect (see here), but Powershell only returns the first matching group (three matches).
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                            
2                              47                                                                                                                                                                               
1                              Total                                                                                                                                                                            
0                              ["Total",47,,,,,,1,2]       

It's easy enough to split this into three separate expressions and process them one at a time. That just feels unnecessary.
Test string:
<script type="text/javascript">
   var resourceFolder = "Test_Results_20240621_0910";
   var blockSize = 50000;
   block0 = [["Total",47,,,,,,1,2],["Group1",29,0,,,,,3,5],["Group2",52,0,,,,,8,4]];
   coverageData = [block0];
</script>

EDIT: I should have pointed out I was using the -match operator as in $test_string -match $exp, then trying to index into the matches using $Matches[i]. It seems the answer is to use $matches = [regex]::Matches($test_str, $exp) instead.
Of course, now I want to know what the difference is between these two methods.
Thank you @user24714692

Try: \[\"(Total|Group1|Group2)\",(\d+),\d*,,,,,\d+,\d+\]?

Try this. It works fine.

The alleged duplicate is about Select-String, whereas the question at hand is about the -match operator.


Your post implies that you're using PowerShell's regex-based -match operator
and are looking for the capture groups in the automatic $Matches variable that -match populates with the matching results.
The problem is that -match by design only ever looks for one match in its input.
While a new -matchall operator - for looking for all matches -  has been   proposed and green-lit in GitHub issue #7867, no one has stepped up to implement it yet.
Thus, for now (as of PowerShell 7.4.x), you need to use the underlying .NET APIs directly , namely the  [regex]::Matches() method:
# Sample input string.
$str = @'
<script type="text/javascript">
   var resourceFolder = "Test_Results_20240621_0910";
   var blockSize = 50000;
   block0 = [["Total",47,,,,,,1,2],["Group1",29,0,,,,,3,5],["Group2",52,0,,,,,8,4]];
   coverageData = [block0];
</script>
'@

# Find all matches of the regex in the input string, and
# report information about each.
[regex]::Matches(
  $str,
  '\["(Total|Group1|Group2)",(\d+),\d*,,,,,\d+,\d+\]'
) | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    FullMatch = $_.Value
    CaptureGroup1 = $_.Groups[1].Value
    CaptureGroup2 = $_.Groups[2].Value
  }
}

The above outputs:
FullMatch               CaptureGroup1 CaptureGroup2
---------               ------------- -------------
["Total",47,,,,,,1,2]   Total         47
["Group1",29,0,,,,,3,5] Group1        29
["Group2",52,0,,,,,8,4] Group2        52

Note:

[regex]::Matches() returns a collection of [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] instances that contain detailed information about each match; the .Value property contains the matched text and the .Groups property contains the capture-group matches (which too have a .Value property), as shown above.
Note that the first capture group is in .Groups[1], whereas .Groups[0] reflects the whole match.

